# Given a array of chars as input, return an array where the elements have been "left shifted" by one

Tags: java

Sample Input #1

`shift({'a','b','c','d','e'})`

Sample Output #1

`{'b','c','d','e','a'}`

```
public class ShiftElements {

    static char[] testcase1 = {'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'c'};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ShiftElements testInstance = new ShiftElements();
        char[] result = testInstance.shift(testcase1);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public char[] shift(char[] elements) {

        if (elements.length >= 2) {
            int temp = elements[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++)
            elements[i] = elements[i + 1];
            temp = elements[elements.length - 1];
        }
        return elements;

    }
```

when i am trying to run testcase it failed my input `{'b','c','d','e','a'}'`. my output `{'c','d','e','a','a'}`
correct output `{'c','d','e','a','b'}`.what to do?

Comment: FYI: Since you're changing the array in-place, there's no need to return the array. Just print `testcase1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
temp=elements[elements.length-1];
```

That should have been the other  way around. You are merely assigning `elements[elements.length-1]` to your local temporary variable, rather than changing `elements[elements.length-1]`.

Change it to:

```
elements[elements.length-1] = temp;
```

Also, make `temp` a `char`, it does not need to be an `int`.

Comment: possible loss of precision at elements[elements.length-1]=temp;

Comment: @PallaviSingh That's because you made `temp` an `int` (not a `char`). It's unneeded, and the loss of precision cannot happen.

Comment: @PallaviSingh That is because you defined `temp` as `int`, not as `char`.

Comment: @amit can you please help me out with this question? i am sending you link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357614/given-arr1-arr2-that-have-been-sorted-in-descending-order-output-an-array-wh/32357765?noredirect=1#comment52598562_32357765

Answer (score 1):

Your last line should be flipped:

```
elements[elements.length-1] = temp;
```

The shifting of the elements can also be done using `System.arraycopy`:

```
char temp = elements[0];
System.arraycopy(elements, 1, elements, 0, elements.length - 1);
elements[elements.length - 1] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use a `String`:

```
public char[] shift(char[] elements) {
    return elements.length < 2 ? 
        elements : 
        (new String(elements, 1, elements.length - 1) + elements[0])
            .toCharArray();
}
```